# jQuery - run multiple animations on multiple elements simultaneously with delay

Tags: jquery, delay, settimeout

I can't seem to answer this myself and I can't seem to find an answer on any forums.

I am cycling multiple div elements using .each() and I need to run animations to both slide the div up and also fade it in at the same time.

```
var intAnimationDelay = parseInt($(this).attr('data-animate-delay'));
$(this).delay(intAnimationDelay).animate({'marginTop' : '50px'}, {duration: (500), queue: true});
$(this).delay(intAnimationDelay).animate({'opacity': '1'}, {duration: 500, queue: true});
```

The problem I have is that delay() adds a delay between the 2 animations. The alternative to this would of course be to use setTimeout() but I cannot do that as it means $(this) is simply targeting the same element everytime.

Can anyone suggest how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you have two animate declarations ? use just one

Comment: try copy and test  https://jsfiddle.net/xogzvsjf/4/

Comment: How about you simply don't add the second delay?   this.delay.animate.animate instead of this.delay.animate.delay.animate

Answer (score 0):

You are probably unnecessarily complicating things a bit here. You can simply animate the other property inside the same function. This will probably suffice:

```
var intAnimationDelay = parseInt($(this).attr('data-animate-delay'));
$(this).delay(intAnimationDelay).animate({'margin-top' : '50px', opacity: '1'}, {duration: (500), queue: true});
```

PS: I assumed you meant margin-top instead of marginTop.